# Set chrome window size on gitlab-runner

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So I have this robotframework-seleniumlibrary test running on gitlab ci. But for some reason I cannot get the resolution higher than 1036x660.
When I run the tests locally it works as expected.

I've tried multiple solutions, and they all work locally but not on GitLab.

For example `Set window size  1600  1200` will set the browser window size to just that. But on GitLab it will be 1036x660.

Any ideas what I might do to solve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your setup is? Which Browser, Driver and Selenium versions are you using. Are there any differences in your setup with respect to your local and GitLab setup?

Comment: The issue didn't have anything to do with that you are asking for. I would guess it has to do with how Windows works.. See my answer for my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial solution:**
The issue resolved itself by running the gitlab-runner service with "Allow service to interact with desktop" privilege.

**Better solution:**
Run acceptance tests using headless Chrome.

Comment: Good that it resolves your symptom, but I'd recommend looking in configuring headless chrome/firefox. This should resolve your issues that require the service to interact with desktop. This is something you'd want to prevent.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will look into it. :)

Comment: @A.Kootstra I did as you said and it was only about adding the `--headless` flag. Reverted the initial fix. Everything is running smoothly. Thanks!